# Error when trying to print ip to a file using terraform local-exec

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, devops, terraform

I am trying to print , private ip of the newly created instances into a host file locally where i run terraform from, to use it for ansible,but terraform is throwing errors, each time I modify my escape characters in the local-exec echo command.

here is the snippet where i am getting error:

```
 provisioner "local-exec"
{
command = " echo \"[servers]\["${aws_instance.seeds.*.private_ip}"\]\" >> /ec2-ansible/hosts"
}
```

expected output in the hosts file:

```
[servers]
ip1
ip2
ip3
```

errors I am getting:

> Failed to load root config module: Error parsing /root/ec2-ansible/main.tf: At 33:1: expected: IDENT | STRING | ASSIGN | LBRACE got: RBRACE
>   Failed to load root config module: Error parsing /root/ec2-ansible/main.tf: At 29:25: illegal char

Please help me out.

Comment: After `[servers]` you have a backslash escape on the `[` but not one on the quote mark that follows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you go in the wrong direction for using both terraform and ansible.

In ansible, you can use [Dynamic Inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#example-aws-ec2-external-inventory-script) to get the host information such as private IPs easily from their tags, size, ami id, etc.

In terraform, if you need the state details and feed to ansible, recommend using [terraform output](https://www.terraform.io/intro/getting-started/outputs.html) to collect the information.